# Fixing the main content of the page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried adding a sidebar to a bootstrap based page and saw a sample online and applied it but I have a problem on how can I tell the sidebar to show while not affecting the main content coz when I toggle the sidebar it shows but it pushes my content to the right. The sidebar template can be found [here](http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/).

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default fixed" role="navigation">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">                                              
    <a href="#menu-toggle" class="navbar-left" id="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
     <a class="navbar-brand center" href="#">Logo</a>
  </div>
  <!-- collapse -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <div class="text-right">
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn btn-raised">Login</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger navbar-btn btn-raised">Register</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
    <header>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1369x500" class="img-responsive">
    </header>
</div>
```

Link to trigger the sidebar:

```
<a href="#menu-toggle" class="navbar-left" id="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

When the sidebar shows, the `<header>` content are pushed to the right and resized. How can I prevent that? I wanted to stay the exact size of the content when sidebar shows. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's what a toggle does. It shows and hides and pushes content. Do you want a menu on the left to always show with the content in the right?

Comment: @mlegg I just wanted to have a sidebar that shows and hides without affecting the main content size.

Comment: I forgot to tell I already solved this by transferring the content outside the `div id="wrapper"` .

Answer (score 0):

Removing left margin should do the job:

```
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```